# Javascript function submit not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
function submit() {
    var text;
    do {
        text = "Não Completou o formelario";
    }
    while (x == "" && y == "");
    document.getElementById("Erros").innerHTML = text;

    var x = document.getElementById("PNome");
    var y = document.getElementById("UNome");
    var Person = function Person(first, last) {
        this.firstName = first;
        this.lastName = last;
    };
    Person.prototype.name = function() {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    };
    var Pessoa = new Person(x, y);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Pessoa.name();
}
```

Comment: could you please describe, what this code *should* do? have you looked into to the console logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return x and y.

```
x=document.getElementById("a")
```

That means x is an object. If you want the value of this object use

```
x=document.getElementById("a").value
```

Comment: tanks you it whas help full

Comment: Please mark it as an answer. That will increase my reputation and will show others that the question is allready answered. :)

Answer (score 0):

This help you :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <form method="post" name="frm" onsubmit="return s()">
            first : <input type="text" id="PNome">
            <br><br>
            last  : <input type="text" id="UNome">
            <br><br>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <p id="Erros"></p>
        <script>
            function s() {
                var x = document.getElementById("PNome");
                var y = document.getElementById("UNome");
                var text = "";
                if(x.value == "" && y.value == ""){
                     text = "Não Completou o formelario";
                     var Errors = document.getElementById("Erros").innerHTML = text;
                     return false;
                }
                  var Person=function Person(first,last)
                    {
                        this.firstName=first;
                        this.lastName=last;
                    };
                    Person.prototype.name=function(){
                        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
                    };
                var Pessoa=new Person(x.value,y.value);
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Pessoa.name();
                return false;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Tiago Araujo , try my code!